# Dynamically subsetting a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question concerning dynamically subsetting a data table. I know that there are numerous threads on stackoverflow which are denominated similarly but unfortunately they didn't lead me to the wanted solution.

The example data set:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(date=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),id=rep(1:5,2),var=c(1:10))
```

For **each ID** I would like to find the subset of *all other* IDs of *all periods* before. In the example data set there are 5 IDs and two periods. If one looks at ID=5 in period 2 the corresponding subset would be that of ID={1,2,3,4) and date=1. In this simple data set I of course can code this by hand:

```
dt[,dt[-.I][date<2],by=id]
```

I however would like to do this automatically. I tried something like

```
dt[,dt[-.I][date < unique(dt$date[.I])],by=id]
```

but this doesn't work unfortunately.

Any helpful comments are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you down rate my question please leave a critique so that I can improve the question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry about that: I've upvoted some of your questions in the past, but eh, I think the basic idea behind the question (creating a huge amount of redundant data) is misguided for most applications (e.g., calculating conditional probabilities as in your earlier q) and that you have asked it several times before. Also, it is misspecified, since you put "each ID...of all periods before" which actually means you want "each ID and date", as seen in the answers below. Relevant meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18552/209360

Comment: Or maybe this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment Frank. Well for most of the question I have been asking here in the last month I know standard R procedures. The problem with the project I am working on at the moment is however that I have a huge data set. Finding the most efficient way of computation for each single step is with what I am struggling at the moment.

Comment: OP, perhaps you can explain why you think you need this. As @Arun's answer shows it's unlikely this transformation would be useful for large data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the faster solution:

```
dta <- data.table(date=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),id=rep(1:5,2),var=c(1:10))
dta[,dta[dta[.I]$id!=dta$id & dta[.I]$date>dta$date],by=list(id,date)]
```

Any comments on how to make this code even faster is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You've to realise that the combinations explode with increase in the number of unique dates/ids. Even for date=1:10 and id=1:10, the answer is of 4050 rows (takes 0.7 seconds) and for date=1:50 and id=1:50, it's already 3001250 rows (takes 6.2 seconds). Having said that, this should work as intended:

```
setkey(dt, date, id)
ans <- dt[!J(1), {d.tmp = date-1; id.tmp = id; dt[CJ(1:d.tmp, 
        setdiff(id, id.tmp))]}, by=list(date, id)]
setnames(ans, make.unique(names(ans)))
setkey(ans, date, id, date.1)

    date id date.1 id.1 var
 1:    2  1      1    2   2
 2:    2  1      1    3   3
 3:    2  1      1    4   4
 4:    2  1      1    5   5
 5:    2  2      1    1   1
 6:    2  2      1    3   3
 7:    2  2      1    4   4
 8:    2  2      1    5   5
 9:    2  3      1    1   1
10:    2  3      1    2   2
11:    2  3      1    4   4
12:    2  3      1    5   5
13:    2  4      1    1   1
14:    2  4      1    2   2
15:    2  4      1    3   3
16:    2  4      1    5   5
17:    2  5      1    1   1
18:    2  5      1    2   2
19:    2  5      1    3   3
20:    2  5      1    4   4
```

Comment: the result is correct, the execution is however too slow for my purpose. if i find a solution i will edit into your response. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016), `data.table` is capabable of *non-equi-joins*.

#### Non-equi self join

```
dta[dta, on = .(date > date), allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0L, 
    .(id, x.date, i.date, i.id, i.var)][
      id != i.id][order(id)]
```

> ```
>     id x.date i.date i.id i.var
>  1:  1      2      1    2     2
>  2:  1      2      1    3     3
>  3:  1      2      1    4     4
>  4:  1      2      1    5     5
>  5:  2      2      1    1     1
>  6:  2      2      1    3     3
>  7:  2      2      1    4     4
>  8:  2      2      1    5     5
>  9:  3      2      1    1     1
> 10:  3      2      1    2     2
> 11:  3      2      1    4     4
> 12:  3      2      1    5     5
> 13:  4      2      1    1     1
> 14:  4      2      1    2     2
> 15:  4      2      1    3     3
> 16:  4      2      1    5     5
> 17:  5      2      1    1     1
> 18:  5      2      1    2     2
> 19:  5      2      1    3     3
> 20:  5      2      1    4     4
> ```

As pointed out be Arun *the combinations explode with increase in the number of unique dates/ids*. Therefore, `allow.cartesian = TRUE` had to be set.

Unfortunately, only `>=`, `>`, `<=`, < and `==` binary operators are possible in a non-equi join but not `!=`. Therefore, the result of the join has to be filtered for equal `id` afterwards.

#### Benchmark

The OP has posted [his own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864841/3817004) asking for further speeding up the code. [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611816/3817004) includes timings for different problem sizes.

So, the benchmark below tries to repeat Arun's mesurements and compares the three different approaches posted so far.

```
library(bench)
library(magrittr)

bm <- press(
  n_date = c(2, 10, 50),
  n_id = c(5, 10, 50),
  {
    dt0 <- CJ(date = seq_len(n_date), id = seq_len(n_id))
    dt0[, var := .I]
    mark(
      arun = {
        dt <- copy(dt0)
        setkey(dt, date, id)
        dt[!J(1), {
          d.tmp = date-1
          id.tmp = id 
          dt[CJ(1:d.tmp, setdiff(id, id.tmp))]
        }, by=list(id, date)] -> arun
      },
      chameau13 = {
        dta <- copy(dt0)
        dta[,dta[dta[.I]$id!=dta$id & dta[.I]$date>dta$date],by=list(id,date)]
      },
      uwe = {
        dta <- copy(dt0)
        dta[dta, on = .(date > date), allow = TRUE, nomatch = 0L, 
            .(id = x.id, date = x.date, date.1 = i.date, id.1 = i.id, var = i.var)][
              id != id.1]
      },
      check = my_check
    )
  }
)
```

As Arun's solution modifies the dataset by reference, all runs start with a fresh copy. The three solutions differ in column names and row order. So, a custom check function is used to enure the results are the same:

```
my_check <- function(x, y) {
  setnames(x, make.unique(names(x)))
  setorder(x, id, date, date.1, id.1)
  setnames(y, make.unique(names(y)))
  setorder(y, id, date, date.1, id.1)
  all.equal(x, y, check.attributes = FALSE) %T>% 
    {if (!isTRUE(.)) print(.)}
}
```

The benchmark timings can be visualised by

```
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

The non-equi-join is by far the fastest method for all problem sizes while OP's own solution is almost always the slowest despite OP's expectations.