# Clarification on Solution to Dynamically Subsetting A Data Table

Tags: r, data.table

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608501/dynamically-subsetting-a-data-table) and answer I think is getting me close to solution I'm looking for. Unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation to comment on the answer.

Can someone please clarify the use of `dta[.I]` in the following

```
require(data.table)
dta <- data.table(date = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)), id = rep(1:5, 2), var = c(1:10))
dta[ , dta[dta[.I]$id != dta$id & dta[.I]$date > dta$date], by = list(id, date)]
```

`dta[.I]` by itself is not valid. Why does it work in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.I` is supported in `j` of `x[i, j, by]`, so... `x1[, x2[.I], by=g]` uses `.I` from `x1`.

If you use `.I` anywhere else, it is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you Frank. That opens up another level of data.table for me.